# Slow Screen Sharing between Macs when using Finder Screen Sharing button

Tags: finder, network, ssh, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I screen share between a 2017 iMac 5K and a 2015 Macbook Pro.  I

1. Locate the remote computer in the Finder's sidebar in the Locations section
2. Select the Screen Share button

It takes about two minutes to "locate" the remote computer and screen sharing finally commences.  The performance is bad enough to make it essentially unusable.

I can use ssh to accomplish the same thing, but over a different port:

1. On the computer I am in front of, `ssh -L 15900:localhost:5900 pauls-macbook.local`
2. From Finder use `Go | Connect To Server...` menu and use the address `vnc://localhost:15900`
3. Enter the remote's local user name and password

This version of screen share is *at least* 10 times as fast!  Unfortunately, the extra steps are really annoying.  Why might the default method work so slowly and what can I do to fix it?